# Rational points on fiber product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I am trying to figure how rational points in fiber products look like. Let $K$ be a field, $A=K[x_1, \ldots, x_n], B=K[y_1, \ldots, y_m]$. Rational points in SpecA and SpecB look like $(x_1-a_1, \ldots , x_n-a_n)$ and $(y_1-b_1, \ldots, y_m-b_m)$ respectively, which correspond to $K$-morphisms $ SpecK \rightarrow SpecA $, $SpecK \rightarrow SpecA$ respectively. Then, by the universal property of the fiber product this morphisms are one-to-one with morphisms $SpecK \rightarrow Spec(A \otimes_K B)$, which correspond to rational points in $Spec(A \otimes_K B)$. Thus, we conclude that the rational points in $Spec(A \otimes_K B)$ are given by tuples of rational points in $SpecA$, $SpecB$.

Is there a way to give explicitly this prime ideal $(x_1-a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n)$ and $(y_1-a_1,\ldots , y_m - a_m)$ correspond to? By explicitly I mean the concrete ideal in $A \otimes_K B$ or its generators in the tensor product.

My idea: $A \otimes_K B = K[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m]$ and the ideal is $(x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n, y_1-a_1, \ldots, y_m - a_m)$, but i am not sure how to prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your identification of the tensor product as the polynomial ring in $n+m$ variables is correct (it's not clear if you're asking about that or just the ideal). For the ideal, note that you want $K$-morphisms $K[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m] \to K$, and of course the kernel of such a map is a maximal ideal. Since the source is just a polynomial ring, the maximal ideals have precisely the structure that you indicated.

Comment: If you were asking about the ring as well, note that the images of the two inclusions are generated by $x_1 \otimes 1,...,x_n \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes y_1,...,1 \otimes y_m$.

Comment: You can build isomorphisms using universal properties of polynomial rings (as free $K$-algebras) and tensor products (of $K$-algebras)

Comment: @TabesBridges Nice, so I know that the ideal $(x_1−a_1, \ldots  ,x_n−a_n ,y_1−a_1, \ldots, y_m−a_m)$ is a rational point, but how do I know that it corresponds to the tuple of rational points $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, $(y_1 , \ldots , y_n)$?

Comment: You've overloaded the notation $a_i$. You want the ideal $(x_1 - a_1,...,x_n - a_n,y_1 - b_1,...,y_m - b_m)$, and the rational points that it corresponds to are $(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $(b_1,...,b_m)$.

Comment: Yes sorry. How do I know that $(x_1-a_1, \ldots, x_n-a_n, y_1-b_1, \ldots, y_m-b_m)$ corresponds to  $(x_1-a_1, \ldots, x_n-a_n)$,  $(y_1-b_1, \ldots, y_m-b_m)$ ?

Comment: This may be tautological depending on your definition of $\operatorname{Spec}$ but you're using that points in $\operatorname{Spec} A$ also correspond to maps $A \to K$ when you say that "by the universal property of the fiber product [these] morphisms are one-to-one with ... $\operatorname{Spec} (A \otimes_K B)$".